# Saving images as a burst on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, camera, photo-gallery, phasset

In iOS, bursts are saved as a group into one. How do I do this? (I am very new to iOS).
I believe that the existing camera saves the images as a PHAsset but how do I create a new instance of this and add each photo?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not possible with the PhotoKit API.